# how to match a specific integer pattern in PHP using reg expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a reg exp to match 1111111/11 pattern, all numbers are integers.

I will be grateful if anyone can please help? I am not that good in regular expressions.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what kind of data this is supposed to match?

Comment: Snark answer: preg_match('%1111111/11%').  Describe the pattern in more detail if you want a better answer, or explain the why patterns you've tried so far don't work.

Comment: Matt Huggins answer below worked for me and that was exactly as he described, 7 integers.. 0-9 and then a forward slash and 2 integers which can be again from 0-9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to match 7 digits, a slash, and then 2 more digits, you'll want a regex pattern like the following:

```
/^[0-9]{7}\/[0-9]{2}$/
```

In PHP, your overall code will look something like this:

```
if (0 !== preg_match('/^[0-9]{7}\\/[0-9]{2}$/', $testString)) {
    // success!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your input string is like `abc1234567/89def` you could use:

```
preg_match('~\D\d{7}/\d{2}\D~', $input);
```